# Stop Prolog program with predicate

Tags: prolog

I am looking for something like the predicate `halt/0` or `abort/0`.

I do not want to use `abort/0` because of the `% Execution aborted` message at the console and I do not want to use `halt/0` because it terminates the `Sicstus Prolog` program.

Is there any other predicates that can be used to stop the program execution?

I already checked the documentation for this topic and I do not seem to find the result I want to see.

Comment: Maybe throw an exception with `throw/1`?

Comment: I can work with that! Thank you

Comment: @PedroPereira: Your question is not specific to SICStus, that's why the tag is not appropriate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Maybe throw an exception with throw/1?

– mat

I managed to achieve what I wanted using that predicate.

Thank you mat.